# rails expiring cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I entered some products data into a table using a migration. I need to expire the page and fragment cache when I update, add, delete products from this table. I created a sweeper for this.

```
class ProductSweeper <  ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  def after_create
    expire_cache
  end

  def after_save
    expire_cache
  end

  def after_update
    expire_cache
  end

  def after_destroy
    expire_cache
  end

  private
  def expire_cache
    expire_page(:controller => 'ProductsController', :action => 'index')
    expire_fragment 'listed_products'
  end
end
```

Then in script/console I update the product name and saved. When I reload my app in the browser it still gives me a cache hit.

Cached fragment hit: views/listed_products (0.2ms)

Can someone tell me how to expire this cache. I will not be adding, updating, deleting products through a controller action.

thanks,
ash

More info:

```
<div>
 <% cache 'listed_products' do %>
  <%= render :partial => "/layouts/product", :collection => Product.listed_products  %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

here is the partial.

```
<ul class="vlist">
 <li>
  <div class="Flt Hday">
   <%=h product.name %>
  </div>
  <div class="Frt Hday">
   <%=h product.cal_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does the <% cache do %> block in your view look like?

Comment: Hi,

added more info. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!